# Reusable Bitbucket pipeline for testing

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org, sfdx-plugin, pipelines, bitbucket

I am new to bitbucket pipeline and I am trying to build a bitbucket script where when a PR is merged to master branch it checks if there is an active scratch org or not.

- If an active scratch org exists it pushes the code.
- If there is no scratch org, it creates one.

So far I have got how to create a scratch org and push it to the org

```
    - step:
         script:
          # Authorize Dev Hub
          - echo $DEV_HUB_URL > devHubURLFile
          - sfdx force:auth:sfdxurl:store -d -f devHubURLFile
          - rm devHubURLFile

          # Create scratch Org
          - sfdx force:org:create -f ./config/project-scratch-def.json --d 30 --setalias scratchorg --setdefaultusername

          # Push source to the scratch Org
          - sfdx force:source:push

          # Run tests
          - sfdx force:apex:test:run --testlevel RunLocalTests --w 30
```

I am not sure how to do the conditional step on how to check if a scratch org exists with 'scratchorg' alias name. Please help.

Comment: `I would like to have a bitbucket script` sounds like you are expecting someone to give you a complete script based on a set of requirements. Please note, this site is not a free coding service. Please update your post with what you have tried and where you are stuck, and maybe someone will be able to help point you in the right direction. Thanks

Comment: BTW, since you cannot guarantee pipelines are executed sequentially (and would not want to force this) the pipeline should always create a new scratch org. Otherwise you may suffer from mixed content from multiple PRs and have spurious behaviour during testing of PRs.

Comment: Do not check for one existing. Always create a new one. See previous comment.

Comment: @PhilW I understand it is not advisable, but I was wondering if there was a way we can do it.

Comment: It isn't just ill advised, this will be a source of inaccurate test coverage and unexpected behaviour. Just imagine a common case where two PRs are merged at a similar time, enough for the execution of the push and the test executions to overlap. The source code state could be inconsistent or a test for one PR could be erased by the push of the other PR before being executed. This way to madness...

Answer (score 1):

You can just query for the org by name or something.  From the docs:

```
sfdx force:data:soql:query -q "SELECT ID, Name, Status FROM ScratchOrgInfo
WHERE CreatedBy.Name = '<your name>' AND CreatedDate = TODAY" -u <Dev Hub org>
```

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_create.htm

So using bash, you can check the return value on the query and then do a conditional.

Also you can add a "sleep" command to wait until your scratch org is created before executing the rest of your commands.

Here is an example for creating webstores.

```
sfdx force:community:create --name "$storename" --templatename "B2B Commerce" --urlpathprefix "$storename" --description "Store $storename"
echo ""

storeId=""

while [ -z "${storeId}" ];
do
    echo_attention "Store not yet created, waiting 10 seconds..."
    storeId=$(sfdx force:data:soql:query -q "SELECT Id FROM WebStore WHERE Name='${storename}' LIMIT 1" -r csv |tail -n +2)
    sleep 10
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you cannot guarantee pipelines are executed sequentially (and would not want to force this since it will artificially slow down your merge process) the pipeline should always create a new scratch org. Otherwise you may suffer from mixed content from multiple PRs and have spurious behaviour during testing of PRs.

As such you should always create a new one.

It isn't just ill advised to try to re-use a scratch org, this will be a source of inaccurate test coverage and unexpected behaviour.

Just imagine a common case where two PRs are merged at a similar time, enough for the execution of the push and the test executions to overlap. The source code state could be inconsistent or a test for one PR could be erased by the push of the other PR before being executed.

This way to madness...

Comment: This problem can also be negated by querying the system and checking if current deployments are in progress before launching a new one (if you needed to).  Also, deployments don't run at the same time, they are queued up in the system and run in the order of the request.